# Oracle IF statement for Fixed Year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a weird condition while filtering oracle data:

1. if there are >=3 month already in the latest year, then only show data from this year and the last year. eg: now is May 2021, show 2020 Jan-Dec data and 2021 Jan-May data
2. if there are <3 month in the the latest year, then show data from the year before last year to now. eg: now is Jan 2021, show 2019 Jan-Dec data, 2020 Jan-Dec data and 2021 Jan

I have code like

```
    SELECT * FROM DB 
    CASE
    WHEN MDY_TIME BETWEEN 
    SELECT MAX(MDY_TIME, YEAR) AS MAX_DATE FROM DB)
    WHERE MAX(MDY_TIME, MONTH)>='3'
    THEN
```

I' sure I'm not using it right and I don't know if I'm even using the right field and don't know how to complete the conditions. This is my first time using SQL.

Data looks like:
[image]

Comment: Unlike other languages, in SQL `IF` is not a flow control structure (don't confuse it with the similar `IF` statement from PL/SQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the `MDY_TIME` column is a `DATE` data-type (if it is not then you should change it to be a `DATE` data-type.)

You want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   DB 
WHERE  MDY_TIME >= CASE
                   WHEN EXTRACT( MONTH FROM SYSDATE ) < 3
                   THEN ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YY' ), -24 )
                   ELSE ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YY' ), -12 )
                   END
AND    MDY_TIME <  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 )
```

Then for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE db (
  mdy_time   DATE,
  year_month VARCHAR2(7)
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( TO_CHAR( mdy_time, 'YYYY_MM' ) ),
  year       INTEGER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM mdy_time) ),
  month      INTEGER
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( EXTRACT(MONTH FROM mdy_time) )
);

INSERT INTO db ( mdy_time )
SELECT ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 - LEVEL )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 36;
```

The output is:

> | MDY_TIME | YEAR_MONTH | YEAR | MONTH |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | 2021_05 | 2021 | 5 |
> | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 2021_04 | 2021 | 4 |
> | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 2021_03 | 2021 | 3 |
> | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 2021_02 | 2021 | 2 |
> | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021_01 | 2021 | 1 |
> | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | 2020_12 | 2020 | 12 |
> | 2020-11-01 00:00:00 | 2020_11 | 2020 | 11 |
> | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | 2020_10 | 2020 | 10 |
> | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 | 2020_09 | 2020 | 9 |
> | 2020-08-01 00:00:00 | 2020_08 | 2020 | 8 |
> | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | 2020_07 | 2020 | 7 |
> | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | 2020_06 | 2020 | 6 |
> | 2020-05-01 00:00:00 | 2020_05 | 2020 | 5 |
> | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 | 2020_04 | 2020 | 4 |
> | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | 2020_03 | 2020 | 3 |
> | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | 2020_02 | 2020 | 2 |
> | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020_01 | 2020 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=95af10143c039486762a897f8d0f8b6c)*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like the below

```
with max_date_sel as (select max(mdy_time) max_dt from DB)
select * from DB,
max_date_sel  
where
case when extract(MONTH from max_dt) >= 3 
and extract(YEAR from max_dt) - Year < 2 then 1
when extract(MONTH from max_dt) < 3 
and extract(YEAR from max_dt) - Year < 3 then 1 end = 1
```

Comment: This appears to make assumptions about the OP's data and assumes that there will never be any future dates in their table and then relies that `MAX(mdy_time)` is (approximately) the current date. I do not think this is a valid assumption that will hold for most data. Particularly, it will get too many rows if the current month is April but no row for April has yet been inserted into the table.

Comment: Your second query has many errors. Missing `FROM` in the first `EXTRACT` then `mmax` instead of `max` and when you fix all of them it raises `ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
where (extract(month from sysdate) < 3 and
       mdy_time >= trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') - interval '1' year
      ) or
      mdy_time >= trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')
```

If you want this based on the most recent year in the table, you can use window functions:

```
from (select db.*, max(mdy_time) over() as max_mdy_time
      from db
     ) db
where (extract(month from max_mdy_time) < 3 and
       mdy_time >= trunc(max_mdy_time, 'YYYY') - interval '1' year
      ) or
      mdy_time >= trunc(max_mdy_time, 'YYYY')
```